# Typescript syntax error in generated definition

Tags: javascript, typescript, syntax-error

Typescript is generating a definition file with syntax errors, but only in one certain occurrence. I would like to understand why, and how I can fix it.

The resulting error is

> TS1005: '>' expected.

Declaration in Typescript (.d.ts)

```js
import {O} from 'moduleO'
import {E} from 'moduleE'
…

export declare type MyResult<T> = O<E<T>>;
```

moduleO/O.d.ts

```js
export declare class O<T> { … }
```

@types/moduleE/index.d.ts

```js
declare module 'moduleE' {
    export interface E<T> { … }
```

Usage (.ts file)

```js
import {MyResult} from '@org/my-module'

export interface I {
    f(): MyResult<any>
}

const myFunc = (): MyResult<any> => …
```

Generated .d.ts file for my usage:

```js
/// <reference path="../../../../../../../../node_modules/@types/moduleE/dist/index.d.ts" />
import {MyResult} from '@org/my-module'
import {O} from 'moduleO'

export interface I {
    f(): MyResult<any>
}

declare const myFunc: () => O<'moduleE'.E<any>>;
```

Obviously, the syntax error is valid. But why is typescript generating this weird case, and only for the function? Where could I look, is there a setting that might provoke this behaviour?

I'm also inside a monorepo, which might add to the issue of model resolution.

1. Why is it resolving the type instead of using it as-is? It's even being imported
2. What could be a reason for the resolution of moduleE to fail?
3. And why only for the second case, and not inside the interface? How could I rephrase the function to work?

Versions:

```
"typescript": "2.9.1",
"webpack": "3.10.0",
"ts-loader": "3.3.1",
```

Comment: Can you show us how you export `O` and `E` from their respective modules? Also, how do you import `MyResult` in the module where you use it in the `myFunc` declaration?

Comment: Hi @Bergi thanks for looking into this. I added the exports of O and E, as well as the import of MyResult to the question.

Comment: Ah, that's the difference between `O` and `E`. It's working when you change the `declare module` into a separate file I guess? Congrats, you found a bug in the typescript compiler! You should open a github issue to report it.

Comment: Actually, it seems to be this bug: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26863 which is more related to monorepo – I didn't think this could cause the issue, but I'm in a monorepo as well.

Comment: It seems to depend on how the function is written as well. Another function in the same file returns a RxResult, but it's correctly used. I'm adding it to the question.

Comment: HAHA, if I write `export declare function myFunc(): MyResult<any> {` it works perfectly: The module gets resolved properly, no `/// <reference`